# I was wondering what you could do with an infinite amount of metal

Tags: technological-development, medieval

Lets say a medieval village was given a well with unlimited molten metal, what could they do with in about two months or so?

Comment: A question to help make matters clear. What metal is in the molten metal well? Iron has different uses from, say, steel from a blast furnace. Molten cooper would be different again.

Comment: this super broad....need the type metal at the very least. molten gold would be great for wreaking the economy.

Comment: If there is infinite matter (metal), that means that the mass of the planet becomes infinite? It's going to end badly.

Comment: May I recommend changing the title to not include "infinite" and change the wording of the question to "... given a well with a virtually unlimited amount of molten metal, limited only by the village's ability to use it."  Infinities cause some people (like me) to break out in hives because people rarely mean it when they use them.  Infinites cause all sorts of unique problems.

Comment: @CortAmmon Or an ore vein that regenerate overtime, indefinitely.

Comment: until Q is in it's original form - I suggest them to make blackhole, so then they could convert their planet ... hm ok, then they could blast their planet.

Comment: Death by heatstroke? What you've described is essentially magma

Answer (score 7):

Within 2 months? **Not a lot** beyond scooping as much liquid metal out to let it cool and then later on resell. Assuming that they actually know it is a Divine Metal Well For The Welfare Of The People, and not a god-given punishment by opening a mouth directly to hell in their backyard, of course.

Once the superstitions have been taken care of, it **could only be used if the local ruler actually took advantage of his Divine Metal Well**. During midieval times, the land belonged to the nobility, and as such the well would too. Even if a village discovered it, they'd first have to inform their ruler, then get permission to use it (if the ruler didn't send someone himself), and then probably have to pay horrendous taxes for its use. Which would once again limit productivity and take a lot longer than 2 months.

Additionally, the middle ages **haven't invented mass production yet**, so they would hoard as much as they can for bad times but not be capable of actually turning the sudden overflow to true productivity. They haven't invented automation yet (industrial revolution), let alone assembly lines (beginning of 20th century), so their metal workers would just proceed as usual. Nothing would change, at least not within 2 months. If the local lords allowed, smiths and metal workers from surrounding villages would arrive to take part in the sudden wealth, but **travel times back then took a really long time**. For news first to get there and then people to move to the source, it would take a lot of time.

Last but not least, **war for the well would probably break out** (the more valuable the metal, the more likely). Then pretty much nothing would get done.

A small, more detailed inspection depending on the metal.

---

**iron**

It is debatable if a European medieval village would know what to do with it. Iron production was done by [Bloomeries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrous_metallurgy) throughout European middle ages, with first blast furnaces (those that actually melt the iron) cropping up around the 1550s but not really replacing the bloomeries until the 18th century. Meaning that it is very probable that nobody has been able to actually melt iron so far. Heating until a red glow, yes, but not melting. Additionally, they wouldn't really have any equipment to a) approach the well (it's a mass of more than 1500°C hot semi-liquid), and then to b) extract iron from the well without the bucket they're using going up in flames or melting (or the rope/chain/whatever they are using to scoop out stuff breaking). Their best bet would be clay, but I'd say it would take a long time until they figured out that it'd be the thing to use.

If they actually took the hurdle of retrieving the stuff, they'd probably just continue on as usual, waiting for the stuff to cool down and then forge it the way they have always done (wrought iron). And then they'd discover that they have pure iron, which is soft enough to cut with a knife. Bloomeries actually produce carbon steel, a lot harder than iron. They'd pretty much throw it out of the window. Some enterprising people might figure out how to lace carbon into the iron or do first cast iron pieces, but 2 months is really not a long time for invention. Even more so during middle ages with their traditional-heavy mentality that scorned invention.

If they didn't discard the metal entirely, they'd be better off scooping as much iron out of their well onto the ground outside, let it cool down, and then sell it as iron bricks (together with an instruction of how to actually make usable iron from it...). It'd ought to make a pretty penny.

---

**Steel**

[Steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel#Ancient_steel) is basically iron laced with small amounts of other elements. Bloomeries produce a carbon-laced steel (=wrought iron), and as such people have already been working with steel for millennia. They just didn't know it -- they called it iron and were done with it. The really interesting properties appeared when people deliberately increased the carbon content and introduced other trace elements -- damascene blades, Indian steel making technology (before Christ even), etc.. Too bad that this kind of knowledge never reached Midieval Europe. They'd probably treat their steel just like in the *Iron* case, and probably realize only very late that they've got something much better than iron on their hands.

Of course, that also depends on what kind of steel they have. High carbon steel (very durable), weathering steel (surface corrodes to form a protective coating for inner iron so that it doesn't rust) or stainless steel (contains chromium and nickle); They basically have absolutely no experience with steel and so they'd only very gradually discover what their steel is capable of. Within 2 months? no chance. They'd just be doing their normal iron work and only later find out specific applications.

---

**Copper, bronze, tin**

Those are metals that have been available in molten form in the middle ages. People know what to do with it and can take full advantage of the abundancy. Well, as much as their society, belief, and lord allows.

---

**Gold, silver**

Hooooh boy. That one's a recipy for disaster. Those metals are so valuable that it is inevitable that war for the well would break out. Or mass production of gold/silver bars, leading to a heavy inflation if continued for years.  But technically, the people could take full advantage of it. Within two months though? Nothing much would change.

---

**Aluminum, platin, titanium, tungsten**

Not usable at all. Aluminum because it is too soft (what would they make from aluminum?), platin and titanium because they don't know what to do with those metals (they'd probably try and treat it like iron with more or less desirable results), and tungsten because they'd never get it out of the well (its melting point is 3500°C, meaning they'd burn alive a long time before approaching their well, and they'd really have absolutely nothing to scoop the tungsten out).

---

**Germanium, Iridium, and other rare earths**

They have absolutely no idea what that stuff is. Or what its properties are. Germanium is said to have some health benifits, but in the quantities that are present around the well I bet it would turn poisonous.

---

**Lead, Antimony, Mercury, and other heavy metals**

Heavy metal poisoning of the entire village preprogrammed. Since the metal is melted, a lot will escape into the atmosphere, let alone that which the people carry away. All those heavy metals were very sought-after medicines during the middle ages, and so a lot of people would be 'cured' with them.

---

**Uranium, Plutonium, and other radioactive metals or isotopes**

Radioactive. Enough said. God-sent plight preprogrammed.

Comment: You wrote "their metal workers" using the plural form. Would there be more than *one* blacksmith?

Comment: In a single village, there could be apprentices next to the black smith. Since it is likely that the local ruler gets involved, other villages might be included in the 'make something out of the metal' task, meaning more than 1 blacksmith is possible again. If you are talking about copper, tin, gold, etc. there could be jewelers (for the fine applications), cauldron builders (eh, don't know what that job is called), and the blacksmith himself that makes use of the metal.